# Python split punctuation but still include it

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the list of strings that I have:

```
 [
  ['It', 'was', 'the', 'besst', 'of', 'times,'], 
  ['it', 'was', 'teh', 'worst', 'of', 'times']
 ]
```

I need to split the punctuation in `times,`, to be `'times',','`
or another example if I have `Why?!?` I would need it to be `'Why','?!?'`

```
import string

def punctuation(string):

for word in string:
    if word contains (string.punctuation):
        word.split()
```

I know it isn't in python language at all! but that's what I want it to do.

Comment: do you mean you want to tokenize? So, if you also had "$3.88" or ":" trailing words in your string would you like to split these up too, keeping delimiters?

Comment: I haven't used the tokenize function before. What will that do?

Comment: There isn't one. But there is in a package http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html .

Comment: Why is there two lists in an outer list?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `finditer` even if the string is more complex.

```
    >>> r = re.compile(r"(\w+)(["+string.punctuation+"]*)")
    >>> s = 'Why?!?Why?*Why'
    >>> [x.groups() for x in r.finditer(s)]
    [('Why', '?!?'), ('Why', '?*'), ('Why', '')]
    >>>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expression, for example:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.findall(r'(\w+)(\W+)', 'times,')
Out[2]: [('times', ',')]

In [3]: re.findall(r'(\w+)(\W+)', 'why?!?')
Out[3]: [('why', '?!?')]

In [4]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?  (Assumes punct is always at end)

```
def lcheck(word):
    for  i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if not word[i].isalpha():
            return [word[0:(i-1)],word[i:]]
    return [word]

value = 'times,'
print lcheck(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

A generator solution without regex:

```
import string
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def splitp(s):
    not_punc = lambda c: c in string.ascii_letters+"'"  # won't split "don't"
    for w in s:
        punc = ''.join(dropwhile(not_punc, w))
        if punc:
            yield ''.join(takewhile(not_punc, w))
            yield punc
        else:
            yield w

list(splitp(s))
```